# Sending a multiple line body email from batch file using a PowerShell command

Tags: html, powershell, email, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a batch file that will send an email using a PowerShell command.
My only challenge is to add multiple lines to the email body.

I declare the message in a variable EmailBody and then I use it in PS command.
The problem is when I receive the email in Outlook 2016, ``r `n are just displayed as plain text.
I tried using HTML tags 
 but that fails because even tho I escape them with ^ in batch file, PowerShell sees ^ and does not like it.

```
@echo off

:: Log File Configuration
SET DateStamp=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%
SET LogFile=F:\WinSCP_%DateStamp%.log

:: Email Configuration
SET SMTPServer=server.com
SET EmailFrom=%computername%@company.com
SET EmailTo="name1@company.com", "name2@company.com"
SET EmailSubject=Subject
SET EmailAttachment=%LogFile%
SET EmailBody="Line1 Line2 Line3"


Some code


Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -Command "& {Send-MailMessage -To '%EmailTo%' -From '%EmailFrom%' -Subject '%EmailSubject%' -SmtpServer '%SMTPServer%' -Body '%EmailBody%' -Attachments '%EmailAttachment%'}"
                    
some code
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're preparing the arguments in a batch file instead of just writing a PowerShell script?

Comment: There is some other code in the script which uses WinSCP. I needed to add email notifications, plus I am not an expert in PowerShell. Also continuing with the batch file would save me hassle to edit Windows Server scheduled tasks.

Comment: @Rudixx, I am betting that you can do the other commands in PowerShell as well.

Comment: And if not can still take the output of batch file into powershell script.

Comment: I doubt that `-executionpolicy remotesigned` has any affect since the `-Command` is provided. Consider using `-NoLogo -NoProfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a revised version of the code from the question. Hopefully, this is also more readable than a one-liner. Writing it all in PowerShell would make it much more simple.

```
SET "EmailSubject=Subject"
SET "EmailBody=Line1 Line1`r`nLine2 Line2`r`nLine3 Line3"
SET "EmailAttachment=%USERPROFILE%\tp.txt"

powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Send-MailMessage" ^
        "-To %EmailTo%" ^
        "-From '%EmailFrom%'" ^
        "-Subject '%EmailSubject'" ^
        "-SmtpServer '%SMTPServer%'" ^
        "-Body '%EmailBody%'" ^
        "-Attachments %EmailAttachment%"
```

Comment: This line:
`SET "EmailBody=Line1`r`nLine2`r`nLine3"`

Must be changed to this line:
`SET EmailBody="Line1 Line1 Line1`r`nLine2 Line2 Line2`r`nLine3 Line3 Line3"`

Otherwise the PowerShell crashes due to spaces in between the words.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Rudixx, the `SET` command does not need to be changed. I replaced the QUOTATION MARK characters on the `-Body` parameter to an APOSTROPHE. It is generally better not to include any kind of quoting in variable values.

Comment: One thing to watch for is if the body contains an APOSTROPE, such as in the word `don't`.  It will need to use two (2) APOSTROPHE characters.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to enter `r`n wherever you want a line break, which PowerShell will evaluate to a carriage return and linefeed (i.e. a Windows style new line).

I would concur with the other replies that doing this in pure PowerShell is probably a better idea, however.

Comment: Think I was missing quotes on the variable. lit's answer works.